# Is there a way to get the cookies from one restTemplate exchange response and set it to another separate request?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cookies

I am relatively new to Spring and Spring Boot and need some much-needed help.

I am working on a project where I need to take the cookies I receive from one `restTemplate` response and pass them on to another request.

The code looks something like this:

```java
ResponseEntity<SomeObject> responseOne  = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.POST, request, SomeObject.class);
```

There are 3 cookies in total and I need them to move from *responseOne* to included in the call of *responseTwo*.

```java
ResponseEntity<SomeOtherObject> responseTwo  = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.POST, request, SomeOtherObject.class);
```

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the cookies from the `responseOne.getHeaders()` method. They are sent as headers with name `Set-Cookie` e.g.:

`Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4054C174E5CD78D5FDD8BD8D155FC233; Path=/yourapp; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: anotherCookie=anotherValue; path=/; HttpOnly`

Parse each header value to separate the cookie name and the cookie value.

Then you just need to set them in the request entity of the second call:

```
SomeObject someObject = ...

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=4054C174E5CD78D5FDD8BD8D155FC233; anotherCookie=anotherValue; cookie3=value3");

HttpEntity<SomeObject> entity = new HttpEntity<>(someObject, headers);

ResponseEntity<SomeOtherObject> responseTwo  = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.POST, request, SomeObject.class);
```